# No syntax highlighting when editing crontab

Tags: cron, vim, highlighting

I am trying to figure out why I don't have syntax highlighting when editing my crontab.

I have both `$EDITOR` and `$VISUAL` set to `/usr/bin/vim`:

```
> echo $EDITOR
/usr/bin/vim
> echo $VISUAL
/usr/bin/vim
```

If I save the crontab to a file and edit it with vim syntax highlighting is enabled.

```
> crontab -l > saved_cronab
> /usr/bin/vim saved_crontab
```

And if I use `:syntax on` while editing the crotab nothing changes

How can I enable highlighting when editing crontab with `crontab -e`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you export these variables (`export EDITOR VISUAL`)?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://serverfault.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://serverfault.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @mdpc Actually it does answer the question, and I'll bet it's the right answer, too.

Comment: @mdpc Probably `export` is an answer, but you are right - I bit misunderstand "you can answer but not comment" policy. Sorry about that. 
Should I remove my another "clarification request" (http://serverfault.com/questions/490255/apache-doesnt-parse-php-on-vhost-while-it-works-on-default/490290#490290) ?

Answer (score 7):

vim doesn't know, that your file saved_crontab is a crontab. Therefore, you don't get a special syntax highlighting for crontabs. Setting the filetype to crontab worked for me. I used:

```
:set ft=crontab
```

You can see the value of filetype with:

```
:set ft?
```

Comment: You can also permanently set the modeline for this file by adding a modeline like `# vim: ft=crontab` to the top of the file. However modelines are disabled by default for security reasons as root and by some distributions.

Comment: Agreed: setting `EDITOR` or `VISUAL` is irrelevant, since OP ran vim directly.  Further clarification would improve the answer, but the information in this question addresses the problem.

Comment: @ThomasDickey OP said using vim directly on a file works, but the question isn't about that - they're asking about `crontab -e`.  When `EDITOR` isn't set, crontab seems to actually be using `vi`, which while it does run vim, disables syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 5):

[The accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68973/18904) is quite poorly explained IMHO, so here's something more to help people solve this issue.

I still fail to understand why `crontab` refuses to pick the editor specified with

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

in my case:

> There are 4 choices for the alternative editor (providing /usr/bin/editor).
>
> ```
>   Selection    Path                Priority   Status
> ------------------------------------------------------------
>   0            /bin/nano            40        auto mode
>   1            /bin/ed             -100       manual mode
>   2            /bin/nano            40        manual mode
> * 3            /usr/bin/vim.basic   30        manual mode
>   4            /usr/bin/vim.tiny    10        manual mode
> ```

And in fact everything correctly points to vim.basic:

> ```
> #> ll /usr/bin/editor
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Oct 20  2014 /usr/bin/editor -> /etc/alternatives/editor
>
> #> ll /etc/alternatives/editor
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Jun 20  2016 /etc/alternatives/editor -> /usr/bin/vim.basic
>
> #> ll /usr/bin/vim.basic
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2.4M Nov 24  2016 /usr/bin/vim.basic
>
> #> ll /usr/bin/vim
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Oct 20  2014 /usr/bin/vim -> /etc/alternatives/vim
> ```

But `crontab` still doesn't care. So, as correctly pointed by *dsznajder*, the solution is to explicitly tell `crontab` what the `$EDITOR` is, via environment variable.

One can `export` it via `.bashrc` or `.profile`, but given that `crontab` is the only one to ignore `/etc/alternatives/`, I preferred to create an alias just for him to make him feel the shame of requiring a custom alias to work (just like for `dmesg -T`).

```
alias crontab='EDITOR=vim crontab'
```

That's it, fixed ✔ :)

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
EDITOR="/usr/bin/vim"
export EDITOR
```

Add this to `~/.bash_profile` to enable this for current user. 
Add this to `/etc/profile/any_file_you_like` to enable this for all users.