# Setting EDITOR variable causes "E886: Can't rename viminfo file" when editing Crontab

Tags: bash, cron, vim, environment-variables

I use Vim as my editor.

I wanted to have syntax colouring when editing Crontab with `crontab -e`.
I followed [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/384471/138166) answer. After setting variable `EDITOR=vim` and exporting it `crontab -e` now shows syntax colours like I wanted. I am editing Crontab as my own user, not using Sudo.

However this causes error when closing Crontab:

```
/tmp/crontab.019kNj" 4L, 278C written
E886: Can't rename viminfo file to /home/me/.viminfo!
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

This happens both when saving changes and when closing without saving.
Error happens only with Crontab, editing files directly with Vim works without problem.
Behavior is similar when using variable `VISUAL` instead of `EDITOR`.

The file `.viminfo` exists in my home dir and has sensible permissions:

```
-rw-------.  1 me me  11K 15.10. 12:49 .viminfo
```

Permissions of `/home/me`  make sense too:

```
drwx------. 33 me me   4,0K 15.10. 13:13 me
```

OS version is `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 7.9 (Maipo)`, Vim version is `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan 29 2020 08:09:16)` and shell is `GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`. Version of Crontab is `crontabs-1.11-6.20121102git.el7.noarch`.

What is causing this error message and how can I enable syntax colouring when editing Crontab without it?

EDIT:

If I rename `.viminfo` the error changes:

```
E138: Cannot write viminfo file /home/me/.viminfo!
```

Comment: Using `vim` as usual does not cause the same type of diagnostic message?

Comment: @Kusalananda No, messages don't appear with normal Vim use.

Comment: @roaima Added information to original post, permissions are sensible.

Comment: And are `/tmp` permissions alright? It would be nice to see the permissions of all directories and files involved in the error message.

Comment: What version does `vim --version | head -n1` show you? Specifically, is it more recent than `8.0`, as there was a bug that got fixed in [8.0.1024](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.0.1028)

Comment: @Quasímodo `/tmp` has `drwxrwxrwt`. I found out that the issue was caused by Selinux.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that this was caused by Selinux policy preventing Crontab from writing to home directories. Similar case has been reported in [Red Hat bugtracker](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=505990):

> Runing "crontab -e" with EDITOR=vim and do some changes to  the cron
> file. When quit from the vim, always gets a warning message: E138:
> Can't write viminfo file /home/hpt/.viminfo! and some avc messages in
> /var/log/messages:
>
> Jun 15 13:51:24 localhost kernel: type=1400
> audit(1245045084.399:17236): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=24910
> comm="vim" name="hpt" dev=dm-6 ino=2301953
> scontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:admin_crontab_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
> tcontext=system_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 tclass=dir Jun 15
> 13:51:24 localhost kernel: type=1400 audit(1245045084.400:17237): avc:
> denied  { create } for  pid=24910 comm="vim" name="v69994"
> scontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:admin_crontab_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
> tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:tmp_t:s0 tclass=dir Jun 15 13:51:24
> localhost kernel: type=1400 audit(1245045084.400:17238): avc:  denied
> { write } for  pid=24910 comm="vim" name="hpt" dev=dm-6 ino=2301953
> scontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:admin_crontab_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
> tcontext=system_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 tclass=dir
> Version-Release number of selected component (if applicable):

Solution is changing the policy to allow this. I don't have details on that change as I don't have Sudo access to this machine so change was done by someone else.